# Activity button on ribbon not working

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

For some reason, the Activity button on the ribbon isn't dropping down the list of available activities when I click on it. This happens in both of the forms I have tried it on, Accounts and Service Cases. I get no script errors or any other errors.

Our environment has been updated up to rollup 11.

Is there anyway I can debug what's going on? I can't seem to get very far with the built-in IE developer tools.

Comment: Basics first. Has the button worked before and then stopped? Can you make the button do something else (a typical actions is `alert("konrad can see you")`?

Comment: The button has worked. It's an out of the box button that comes with a default CRM install.

Comment: What Activity button, where? Which form, which Ribbon tab, which group, what exact button label. I don't have a button on the form ribbon for Account nor Case which is labelled "Activity". I can force the "Activity" group on the "Add" ribbon to appear as a button with a flyout for the group, but only if I use an extremely narrow window.

Comment: One example: Go to Workplace > Accounts. Open an account. Click on the Activities link. The ribbon will change and show a "Add New Activity" button. When you click on this, it should give you a dropdown list of activities to choose from.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get the drop down as shown in the screenshot in my answer?! (Sorry for the Swedish version. Once I've realized that, I already closed CRM/Paint.NET and I'm a lazy... hrmp... optimizing person.)

Comment: That's correct. Clicking on the button does nothing, no error, no drop down, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> but it's not as fun as it may sound. Also, the behavior seems odd. I can't reproduce it. Would you mind posting a screenshot?

[image]

Comment: Sure. See the yellow highlighted button in the image at http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/3013/screenqi.png

I got to this via Service > Cases > Open an existing active case > Click on Activities.

I have tried debugging with F12 in IE but it's impossible to trawl through the sheer amount of javascript. I don't see any errors being generated in the console either.

Comment: Have you tried restarting IIS? Does that happen for all new organizations? Does that happen when you use different browsers? I'm beating around the bush now in hopes of hitting something.